# Elasticsearch composite aggregation inner aggregation only returning 10 results

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

I am using elaticsearch `v7.1.0` to perform composite aggregation to paginate my results.

The data in the index I am querying and aggregating looks like this.

```
{
    "sequence": "SEQ-A123",
    "timestamp": "2022-05-11T12:26:54Z",
    "owner": "b96e1abb08d44a6a9871f567aa392167",
    "serialNo": "A5645",
    "value": 45,
    "ctags": [
        {
            "name": "project",
            "value": "cd8041f817634e7784b8c0cb5b069d4b"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "sequence": "SEQ-B123",
    "timestamp": "2022-05-11T12:26:54Z",
    "owner": "b96e1abb08d44a6a9871f567aa392165",
    "serialNo": "A8456",
    "value": 87,
    "ctags": [
        {
            "name": "project",
            "value": "cd8041f817634e7784b8c0cb5b069d4b"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "sequence": "SEQ-C123",
    "timestamp": "2022-05-11T12:26:54Z",
    "owner": "b96e1abb08d44a6a9871f567aa392165",
    "serialNo": "A59",
    "value": 87,
    "ctags": [
        {
            "name": "project",
            "value": "cd8041f817634e7784b8c0cb5b069d4b"
        }
    ]
}, ...
```

The Query I am executing on elasticsearch is this.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2022-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2022-05-30T23:59:59.999Z"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "sequence.keyword": [
              "SEQ-A123",
              "SEQ-B123"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "serialNo.keyword": "test"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sequence": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "bkt_sequence": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "sequence.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "after": {
          "bkt_sequence": ""
        },
        "size": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "serialNo": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "serialNo.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "usageStats": {
              "stats": {
                "field": "value"
              }
            },
            "ctags": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "_source": {
                  "include": [
                    "owner",
                    "ctags"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result I am getting against this query looks like this.

```
{
    "took": 6,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 94,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "sequence": {
            "after_key": {
                "bkt_sequence": "SEQ-B123"
            },
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": {
                        "bkt_sequence": "SEQ-A123"
                    },
                    "doc_count": 47,
                    "serialNo": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 37,
                        "buckets": [
                            "0": {
                                "key": "A5645",
                                "doc_count": 1,
                                "ctags": {
                                    "hits": {
                                        "total": {
                                            "value": 1,
                                            "relation": "eq"
                                        },
                                        "max_score": 2,
                                        "hits": [
                                            "0": {
                                                "_index": "seq-serial",
                                                "_type": "_doc",
                                                "_id": "1",
                                                "_score": 2,
                                                "_source": {
                                                    "owner": "b96e1abb08d44a6a9871f567aa392167",
                                                    "ctags": [
                                                        "0": {
                                                            "name": "project",
                                                            "value": "cd8041f817634e7784b8c0cb5b069d4b"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "usageStats": {
                                    "count": 1,
                                    "min": 45,
                                    "max": 45,
                                    "avg": 45,
                                    "sum": 45
                                }
                            },
                            "1": {
                                "key": "A5646",
                                "doc_count": 1,
                                "ctags": {
                                    "hits": {
                                        "total": {
                                            "value": 1,
                                            "relation": "eq"
                                        },
                                        "max_score": 2,
                                        "hits": [
                                            "0": {
                                                "_index": "seq-serial",
                                                "_type": "_doc",
                                                "_id": "27",
                                                "_score": 2,
                                                "_source": {
                                                    "owner": "b96e1abb08d44a6a9871f567aa392169",
                                                    "ctags": [
                                                        "0": {
                                                            "name": "project",
                                                            "value": "cd8041f817634e7784b8c0cb5b069d4b"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "usageStats": {
                                    "count": 1,
                                    "min": 85,
                                    "max": 85,
                                    "avg": 85,
                                    "sum": 85
                                }
                            },
                            "2": {
                                ...
                            },
                            "3": {
                                ...
                            },
                            "4": {
                                ...
                            },
                            "5": {
                                ...
                            },
                            "6": {
                                ...
                            },
                            "7": {
                                ...
                            },
                            "8": {
                                ...
                            },
                            "9": {
                                ...
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": {
                        "bkt_sequence": "SEQ-B123"
                    },
                    "doc_count": 47,
                    "serialNo": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 37,
                        "buckets": [
                            "0": {
                                "key": "A8456",
                                "doc_count": 1,
                                "ctags": {
                                    "hits": {
                                        "total": {
                                            "value": 1,
                                            "relation": "eq"
                                        },
                                        "max_score": 2,
                                        "hits": [
                                            "0": {
                                                "_index": "seq-serial",
                                                "_type": "_doc",
                                                "_id": "48",
                                                "_score": 2,
                                                "_source": {
                                                    "owner": "b96e1abb08d44a6a9871f567aa392167",
                                                    "ctags": [
                                                        "0": {
                                                            "name": "project",
                                                            "value": "cd8041f817634e7784b8c0cb5b069d4b"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "usageStats": {
                                    "count": 1,
                                    "min": 45,
                                    "max": 45,
                                    "avg": 45,
                                    "sum": 45
                                }
                            },
                            "1": {
                                "key": "A7590",
                                "doc_count": 1,
                                "ctags": {
                                    "hits": {
                                        "total": {
                                            "value": 1,
                                            "relation": "eq"
                                        },
                                        "max_score": 2,
                                        "hits": [
                                            "0": {
                                                "_index": "seq-serial",
                                                "_type": "_doc",
                                                "_id": "74",
                                                "_score": 2,
                                                "_source": {
                                                    "owner": "b96e1abb08d44a6a9871f567aa392169",
                                                    "ctags": [
                                                        "0": {
                                                            "name": "project",
                                                            "value": "cd8041f817634e7784b8c0cb5b069d4b"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "usageStats": {
                                    "count": 1,
                                    "min": 85,
                                    "max": 85,
                                    "avg": 85,
                                    "sum": 85
                                }
                            },
                            "2": {
                                ...
                            },
                            "3": {
                                ...
                            },
                            "4": {
                                ...
                            },
                            "5": {
                                ...
                            },
                            "6": {
                                ...
                            },
                            "7": {
                                ...
                            },
                            "8": {
                                ...
                            },
                            "9": {
                                ...
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there are total 94 documents that are hit with this query.
47 belongs to the SEQ-A123 bucket and other 47 belongs to SEQ-B123 bucket but out of 47 only 10 documents are returned in the response.

How can I get all 47 documents in the result and still use pagination at `sequence` field level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) by default returns only *top 10 documents*.

Just need to add [`size` in the terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size) in the aggregation `serialNo`.

Below is how your query would look like:

```
POST test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2022-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2022-05-30T23:59:59.999Z"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "sequence.keyword": [
              "SEQ-A123",
              "SEQ-B123"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "serialNo.keyword": "test"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sequence": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "bkt_sequence": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "sequence.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "after": {
          "bkt_sequence": ""
        },
        "size": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "serialNo": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "serialNo.keyword",
            "size": 100                    <----------- Note this here
          },
          "aggs": {
            "usageStats": {
              "stats": {
                "field": "value"
              }
            },
            "ctags": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "_source": {
                  "include": [
                    "owner",
                    "ctags"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```